# How to order a list<object> by its current order so it will be accepted by PagedList?

Tags: c#, linq, list, pagedlist

Problem: "The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities. The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method 'Skip'."

```
list2 = list1.Where(a).OrderBy(x => x.Something).Union(list1.Where(x).OrderBy(x => x.SomethingDifferent));
return list2.ToPagedList(...);
```

I assume this happens because it requires a new 'OrderBy' after the 'Union'. Is there any way to turn this into an OrderedList while keeping the current order from the Union?

Is there a way to add another OrderBy which doesn't actually change the order like:

```
list2 = list1.Where(a).OrderBy(x => x.Something).Union(list1.Where(x).OrderBy(x => x.SomethingDifferent)).OrderBy(x => x.NothingThatWillAffectTheOrder);
```

**EDIT**

To make this more clear, I will explain using a practical example.

Say a user searches in a movie database and you want to show Titles that contain the search string before say Actors' names that contain the search string.

```
list = movies.Where(x => x.Title.Contain...).Union(movies.Where(x => x.Actors.Contain..)
```

PagedList will not accept this because it is not ordered but ordering this list will defeat the purpose of the Union. Is there a 'work around' to make this an ordered list while keeping the current order?

Comment: I deleted my previous answer because I didn't fully understand your question.  I don't get any issue with regard to the 'Skip' method when using PagedList from https://github.com/TroyGoode/PagedList.  Is that the one you are using?

Comment: Yes that is the one I'm using. The problem is because the two OrderBys happen before the Union so PagedList won't accept it. I'll edit my question to give a better example.

Comment: I can't see why you're getting that error, but I added a new answer with a completely functional implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you are getting the error that you are.  However, I was able to write a program based on the information that you provided that works properly.  Have a look at the following.  Hopefully it will help you spot exactly what you are doing differently.  *Note that my implementation of ToString() uses a feature new in C# 6.  If you're on an older version of C#, you'll have to slightly modify that line.*

```
using PagedList;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Actor
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public List<string> Actors { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{Title} featuring {string.Join(", ", Actors)}";
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Actor> movies = new List<Actor>()
            {
                new Actor() { Title = "Star Wars", Actors = new List<string>() {  "Mark Hamill", "Harrison Ford" } },
                new Actor() { Title = "Indiana Jones and The Raiders of the Lost Ark", Actors = new List<string>() {  "Karen Allen", "Harrison Ford" } },
                new Actor() { Title = "Indiana Jones and The Temple of Doom", Actors = new List<string>() {  "Kate Kapshaw", "Harrison Ford" } },
                new Actor() { Title = "Indiana Jones and The Kingdom of the Crystal Skull", Actors = new List<string>() {  "Cate Blanchett", "Harrison Ford" } },
                new Actor() { Title = "Jessica Jones", Actors = new List<string>() {  "Krysten Riter", "David Tennant" } },
                new Actor() { Title = "The Wizard of Oz", Actors = new List<string>() {  "Judy Garland" } },
            };

            var list = movies.Where(x => x.Title.Contains("Jones")).Union(movies.Where(x => x.Actors.Contains("Harrison")));

            var pagedList = list.ToPagedList(1, 2);

            foreach (var movie in pagedList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(movie);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a select overload that lets you include the ordinal, so perhaps you could do something like:

```
list1.Where(a).OrderBy(x => x.Something)
    .Union(list1.Where(x).OrderBy(x => x.SomethingDifferent))
    .Select((item,idx) => new { item, idx })
    .OrderBy(x => x.idx);
```

Unfortunately that means you are not selecting the same type as before. But depending on what you are actually doing with it, maybe you can just flatten it with something like:

```
 .Select((item,idx) => new { item.Title, item.SomeOtherProperty, idx })
```

Which if whatever is consuming it can duck type, might be viable

Comment: Funny the question is 22 hours old and we both answered within seconds of each other.